# Find regex in next line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

My content is this this form:

```
<tr>    
    <td width="50%" align="right" valign="middle">Email </td> 
    <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle"> unique@gmail.com </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td width="50%" align="right" valign="middle">Code </td>
    <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle">twenty</td>
</tr>
 <tr>   
    <td width="50%" align="right" valign="middle">Code12 </td>
    <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle">forty</td>
</tr>
```

What regex should i use if i want to extract "twenty" ie data accociated with "Code"

I tried to extract the whole line, but empty response

```
$c=$m->content();
($a) = $c =~ /Code(.*?)tr>/;
print "$a\n";
```

Comment: @Mariano: added what i attempted

Comment: You should really use an html parser... As for your regex, you need to specify the `/s` modifier, for `.*` to match `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to parse HTML with a regex, that way madness and very broken code lies. Instead, use the existing XML tools. For searching in HTML (which can be treated as XML) use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). There are many Perl implementations. I would recommend [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) which uses the fast and well maintained libxml2 C library.

Here's an example of how you'd get the content of the cell next to the "Code " cell.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

# Parse the HTML into an XML::LibXML::Document
my $parsed_html = XML::LibXML->load_html( string => <<'HTML');
<tr>    
    <td width="50%" align="right" valign="middle">Email </td> 
    <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle"> unique@gmail.com </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td width="50%" align="right" valign="middle">Code </td>
    <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle">twenty</td>
</tr>
 <tr>   
    <td width="50%" align="right" valign="middle">Code12 </td>
    <td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle">forty</td>
</tr>
HTML

# Find all the rows where the first cell contains "Code" ignoring whitespace.
my @code_rows = $parsed_html->findnodes(q{//tr[normalize-space(td[1])='Code']});

# In each of the Code rows, get the value of the second cell.
for my $row (@code_rows) {
    say $row->findvalue(q{td[2]});
}
```

XML::LibXML and XPath are large but they're well worth the investment if you're going to be working with HTML and XML. It will save you endless hours debugging all those special cases your regexes don't handle. Most of what you need is in [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Node).